# Is there any way to get the status of the map reduce script we triggered? NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am triggering a `mapreduce` script in the `POST` of my `suitelet`.
Is there any way to show the status of the triggered `mapreduce` script whether is done processing or completed, in my `suitelet`?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use the task module to get the status (view the next example)

```js
var myTaskId = myTask.submit();

var o_taskStatus = task.checkStatus({
taskId: myTaskId
});

do {
o_taskStatus = task.checkStatus({
    taskId: myTaskId
});

if (o_taskStatus.status === task.TaskStatus.FAILED) {
    // do something
} else if (o_taskStatus.status === task.TaskStatus.COMPLETE) {
    // do something
}

} while (o_taskStatus.status !== task.TaskStatus.COMPLETE && o_taskStatus.status !== task.TaskStatus.FAILED);
```

but keep in mind the time limit in your suitlet